# How to search for dollar sign or exclamation mark?

Tags: support, search

I want to look for questions/answers in which `!$` appears. I type `!$` in the Search bar in https://stackoverflow.com/search and I get 0 results. I also try escaping those symbols `\!\$` and still nothing.

I went through [How do I search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but couldn't find anything related to this special characters.

How should I search for such characters?

Comment: cross-site related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken

Comment: You can use http://symbolhound.com (created by another SO user), which is a search engine for special characters. It indexes SO and a few other pages.

Comment: check out [stackse](http://stackse.com)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## This is possible with the regular search!

Just use [`code:"!$"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%21%24%22) to search for all occurrences of `!$` in code.

Comment: Wow, this is new! I don't see any reference in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/209901), when and where was this announced?

Comment: @fedorqui It [wasn't announced](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675) and it's been around since [2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132613/323179). (I only learned about it yesterday, immediately before writing this answer...)

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, SE elasticsearch ignores symbols. You should use other tools, like http://symbolhound.com/, as suggested by l4mpi to obtain results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://data.stackexchange.com/ but you need to know a modicum of SQL and probably familiarize yourself with the SE database schema a bit.

Here is a query I composed to search for `$*` and `$@` in [bash] questions just now. You should be able to fork it and adapt it for your own needs.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355107/code-search-and-bash-or-sh

Somebody who is more familiar with the platform would perhaps be able to generalize it and encapsulate it into a useful search engine for the SE family of sites. As it is, there is certainly a bit of a threshold.

Comment: Oh, I see now that @rene's comment eventually leads to a similar, but somewhat more featureful query; http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/284162

Comment: The unfortunate drawback of this is the fact that the results may be up to a week old. I have also run into problems with timeouts, but I will just chalk that up to the fact that I was trying to run broad LIKE queries...