# Deleting an answer on a low quality question?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I recently answered a question which was poor quality, it was pointed out to me that I shouldn't have done this.

I commented asking whether to delete it but I think the question itself was removed before I got an answer to my comment.

So my question is, should I have deleted the answer because the question was poor, or should I leave my answer there?

Comment: can the question be improved?

Comment: @amuse the problem was that it was simple and on hindsight would've been easily solved through googling the basics of the language.

Comment: @amuse I think the question should be improved whenever it can be. But in my experience, low quality questions are often unsalvageable.

Comment: @JoeSmart doesn't that make it somewhat subjective? Experience developers can google much better, since they know related search terms, whereas for a novice it would've still proved to be helpful. Just my 2 cents on it.

Comment: @ShamasS that is pretty much why I answered it. There was a definite answer and it wasn't a broad question or subjective. It was a clearly stated question with an equally clear answer. The only issue was that it was so simple.

Comment: @rene the question itself has now been deleted. The question was asking what `!=` meant in python, I answered explaining what it meant along with some (simple) example code.

Comment: @rene the links leads to a "page not found"

Comment: @rene I didn't know that, learn something new everyday! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603516/what-does-mean-in-python/32603694#32603694

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603516/what-does-mean-in-python/32603694#32603694) is indeed low quality.

> [image: low quality]

Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **NOT** Yahoo Answers, where you can type anything you like in the question box and anyone who sees (un)fit types something in the answer box.

We want questions and answers to be useful for future visitors. To make that happen the community moderates fiercely all posts. That moderation is done with (down) votes, close votes/flags, delete votes, edits and comments.

When you arrive at any question, specially the ones that look easy, do a search, either on google, in the language/tool documentation or on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+equal)<sup>1</sup>.

If you find a duplicate, use a flag to indicate that or leave a comment. If the question is answered from the documentation or Google, down vote for lack of research.

When you answer such questions you achieve at least three things:

- the OP learned that on Stack Overflow you can ask what ever you want without any effort and get an answer.
- the friends of the OP get told that Stack Overflow is a great place to ask no-effort questions.
- you risk getting down votes, not because your answer is technical bad but because your answer has impact on the overall quality of the site and that is not useful (a reason for down voting posts).

**tl;dr** To answer your question

> should I have deleted the answer because the question was poor, or should I leave my answer there

You shouldn't have answered in the first place. But after that, yes, immediate deletion is warranted. In the screenshot you see that [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) took the honors for you, after 5 other members close voted the question.

<sup>1. unfortunately searching for [symbols is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289671/how-to-search-for-dollar-sign-or-exclamation-mark)</sup>

Comment: To be fair, googling it isn't very helpful. https://goo.gl/YuHXd6 no mention of `!=` on the first 3 pages. Still an extremely low quality question though.

Comment: Oh, I thought searching for symbols was only broken on SE but it's broken on the interwebz as well ... @DJMcMayhem

Comment: I've used http://symbolhound.com/ for symbol searches in the past. Sometimes it helped; others not. Better than not being able to search at all, though.

Comment: This would be a great answer if not for the fact that (at least in the Python tag) there are several users, some with very high rep, who make a habit of answering these awful questions on the off-chance that they'll get an accept, and maybe even a few votes from other zero-research users. It always comes as a nice surprise to see this type of question getting deleted like it should be.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem - Both Google and Bing suggest some reasonable options for "python !=". I.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=python+!%3D lists python site and docs links as top results. Clicking on any "beginners"/"getting started" guide from the list of results  and searching for "!=" on resulting page would give an answer. I'm not sure how far that is from "tried to search" soo...